# sklearn LassoCV usage, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, lasso

This is hopefully a very simple question for anyone who has used `sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV` successfully.

I'm doing my first Lasso regression on a very simple simulated data set as follows... I'm getting unsatisfactory results and I want to know what it is I'm doing wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp

X = np.random.normal(0, 10, 100)
e = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
# coefficients
b0, b1, b2, b3 = 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3
# target
Y = b0 + b1 * X + b2 * X**2 + b3 * X**3 + e
# the dataset x**1, ..., x**10 
data = pd.DataFrame({"Y":Y, "X1":X})
for i in range(2, 11): data["X{:d}".format(i)] = data["X1"]**i

X = data.drop(axis = 1, labels = 'Y')
Y = data['Y']

# standardize the data
scaler = StandardScaler()
Xscl = pd.DataFrame( data = scaler.fit_transform(X), columns = ['X'+`i` for i in range(1, 11)] )

# lasso constraints
alphas = np.logspace(-3, 1, 1000)
# perform regression with 10 fold cv
model = LassoCV(alphas = alphas, cv = 10, max_iter=10000, tol=0.0001, eps = 0.0001)
result = model.fit(Xscl, Y)

# reverse scale coefficients and plot fit over data
coeff = model.coef_/scaler.scale_
x1 = np.linspace(0., 10., 100)
pp.plot(X['X1'], Y, 'o')
pp.plot(x1, np.polyval(coeff[::-1], x1), '--')

# print(model.coef_)
# [-6.3122168  
# 38.18296697 
# 30.20713128 
# 16.3567352   
# 7.30950212  
# 2.27074138
# 0.         
# 0.         
# -1.16784659 
# -1.88575215]
```

plotting the fit over the data gives the following. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scaling your coefficients, transform your test data using your StandardScaler.

```
x1 = np.linspace(0., 10., 100)
data = pd.DataFrame({"X1":x1})
for i in range(2, 11): data["X{:d}".format(i)] = data["X1"]**i
x1scl = scaler.transform(data)
yp = model.predict(x1scl)
plt.plot(X['X1'], Y, 'o')
plt.plot(x1, yp, '--')
```

I tried it, this works. By the way, you are dividing your model coefficients by the std. of corresponding feature. But, you ignore the effect of the mean.

Comment: I'd rather rescale my coefficients so I can compare to the true values directly. Also can you point out where I am ignoring the mean effect and show me how I should be taking it into account? Thanks!

Comment: StdScaler subtracts your column mean and divides by column deviation. You don't take it into account while using polyval (also, i think you cannot directly do that).